# Xamarin.Forms.CarouselPage title color

Tags: textcolor, xamarin.forms

I have a code in my mobile application written with Xamarin.Forms :

```
public CarouselPage CreateMenuPage() {
    var menuPage = new CarouselPage();
    menuPage.Title = "Application name";
    menuPage.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    return menuPage;
}
```

As a result, the page title is invisible, because it has the same color (white) as the background.
How to set custom font color for title of CarouselPage?

Answer (score 0):

The page title is not invisible, it wont be displayed as Pages that are opened modally or are at the root of your app don't display a title.

In Xamarin Forms you set the Title on each Page and these values are used by containers (like NavigationPage, TabbedPage, etc) when they need to describe their children. Any Page that are intending to add to a container should have the Title set (at least).

As an example the below Test Title can be seen but not the Carousel Content Page Titles.

```
    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        var MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();
        MainPage.Master = new ContentPage();

        MainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new CarouselPage
            {
                Children = 
                {
            new ContentPage {Content = new BoxView {Color = new Color (1, 0, 0)}, Title = "Page 1"},
            new ContentPage {Content = new BoxView {Color = new Color (0, 1, 0)}, Title = "Page 2"},
            new ContentPage {Content = new BoxView {Color = new Color (0, 0, 1)}, Title = "Page 3"}
                },

                Title = "test",
            });
        return MainPage;
    }
```